# FOSUserBundle: Why I get exception on login_check?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I try to configure FOSUserBundle in Symfony 2.7 but I still get "You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration." exception.

I searched vendor folder for Security Controller and I found that checkAction throws such exception.

I would like to allow 
admin to log into /admin section, 
and editors to /editor section.

I use two ways of logging: one is in_memory, and second fos_userbundle. This is my security.yml

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    Inpero\PageBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_EDITOR:      ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin: { password: pass1, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

# the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
# for specific sections of your app
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    # the login page has to be accessible for everybody

    page_login:
        pattern: ^/admin/login$
        security: false

    page_admin:
        pattern: ^/admin
        form_login:
            check_path: my_page_check
            login_path: my_page_login
        logout:
            path:   my_page_logout
            target: /

    editor_login:
        pattern: ^/editor/login
        security: false

    editors:
        pattern: ^/editor
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path:     /editor/login_check
            login_path:     /editor/login
            failure_path:   /editor/login
            default_target_path: /editor/
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:
          path: fos_user_security_logout
          target: /
        anonymous:    ~


# with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
# of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-book-access-control-matching-options
access_control:
    - { path: ^/efconnect, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
    - { path: ^/elfinder, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/editor, role: ROLE_EDITOR }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There should be $ after editor_login.pattern: ^/editor/login Should be ^/editor/login$